# Android RatingBar: handler for same star tapped as current rating?

Tags: android

I have a RatingBar (as a "star bar") implementation I'm working on, and while I have it going just fine using the *onRatingChanged()* delegate method, there's a glaring omission (or something I'm just blind to) in the API: there's only this one event firing when the rating actually *changes*, not when the user taps the same star that it's already set at.

For example, if I am showing a 3/5 star rating in the rating bar, tapping 2 or 5 sets fires *onRatingChanged()* but tapping 3 does absolutely nothing.

I am capturing the onTouch and allowing it to propagate (for other custom UI purposes) but I don't have a reference to which star was tapped of course. If I did, I could compare that to the current *getRating()* and handle the "same star tapped" case.

Anyone else tried to accomplish this yet or have any tips on other methods I could explore? I've been up and down the RatingBar hierarchy and don't see anything helpful. Ideally *onRatingChanged()* would just fire with the same rating and I could handle it there. :/

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Bas van Stein below, I ended up using a Runnable to delay the execution of my current vs. new rating check in the ACTION_UP check of my touch event handler. It's not pretty but it does seem to work (TBD on device). Keep in mind this is a subclass impl of RatingBar itself:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // we only want to handle this on DOWN or MOVE (drag)
    int action = event.getAction();

    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starbar touched; current rating=" + getRating());

        // do stuff for UI purposes here

        // capture the current rating before onRatingChanged does anything    
        currentRating = getRating();
    }

    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                float newRating = getRating();

                if(currentRating == newRating) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Same rating tapped; would unrate");
                    // do something UI related here
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "New rating, will just show it");
                    // this just falls through to my onRatingChanged()
                }
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, (long) 0.1);
    }

    // allow the touch event to propagate
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually do know which rating is being pressed because this is always the current rating when the touch event starts (touch_down).

The rating change function will be called after both touch events so what you should do is check the rating at the moment the touch action starts `ACTION_DOWN` and the rating a bit after the touch action ends `ACTION_UP`. If both are the same, you know the same rating has been given (the current rating), and if it has been changed, your `onChangeRating` listener will catch it.

```
private current_rating = 0;
ratingBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            current_rating = ratingBar.getRating()
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                 if (current_rating == ratingBar.getRating() ){
                     //touched but no change between down and up, so fire the same rating.
                 }
              }
            }, 100);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like it's good in theory, but unfortunately I found onRatingChanged doesn't fire until after the ACTION_UP event. :/

Comment: As another complication, I found that setting stepSize will also fire onRatingChanged because it requests a progress refresh (this was a huge PITA which made it difficult to test your answer)

Comment: Ok, in that case you could (hacky) fix it by setting a postdelay handler that fires after a tenth of a second.

Comment: Somehow I don't think our pseudo UX guy is gonna like that, but I'll give it a try thanks.

Comment: I agree its not optimal or pretty but sometimes the dirty way is the only (reasonable fast) one.

Comment: Starting to wonder if subclassing ProgressBar was the best idea for a RatingBar... /s

Comment: You can also try different alternatives such as https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar

Comment: If you'd like to edit your answer to include the delay idea, I'll upvote ya. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @the_dude_abides I did :), good luck with the further developments.

Answer (score 0):

I've made simpler solution, you won't need hack with Handler, just don't pass touch further.

```
private previous_rating = 0;
ratingBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            previous_rating = ratingBar.getRating()
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (current_rating == ratingBar.getRating() ){
                //pressed same star as before, do your action here
                return true; //we have consumed this event
            }
        }
        return false; //do whatever ratingBar has to do
    }
});
```